# COMEFROM control flow

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, control-flow, comefrom

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMEFROM) COMEFROM flow control is considered a joke, unreadable or downright harmful. I'd imagine such a feature would be very useful in AOP scenarios (ie. adding logger to methods without adding logger calls to methods).

Does the downside of non-obviousness of such a control structure outweigh the potential usefulness? Are there any other downsides to consider?

Prompted to ask this question because of [this](http://twitter.com/#!/jonskeet/status/68211366577704960).

Comment: From the subject line, I guessed I might be the cause :)

Comment: Adding logging this way is (in effect) saying that it doesn't matter that the control flow is very difficult to follow, because you don't "need to know" about the logging. In practice weaving is implemented without a generalized COMEFROM syntax. If you wanted to add AOP to a language which doesn't easily support it then I'm not sure COMEFROM would actually help all that much. In C for instance, to weave you would need to COMEFROM places that aren't in scope for a GOTO, so it's not just syntactic sugar to avoid cluttering your code, it's all the mechanisms needed for weaving that aren't in C.

Comment: @Jon it's not my fault you have interesting ideas :)

Comment: @Steve I agree comefrom != weaving. I asked the question as I was surprised something I'd considered useful is considered harmful.

Comment: if something is both useful and harmful, the fix is to find a more restricted version of it that has most of the use and little of the harm. Hence structured programming to reduce harmful use of GOTO, and (as it were) join points to reduce harmful use of COMEFROM.

Answer (score 1):

For starters is basically useless in any modern language because you need to either:

- Reference the position to jump from by line number, and these are volatile.
- Place a marker or label in the code to denote a position that can be jumped from, thus destroying any possible benefits of not needing to do this.

Also:

- Makes any kind of debugging by inspection essentially useless.
- Can't really capture any context from where it jumped unless you keep variables persistant, which is asking for trouble.

A much better idea would be to instead:

- Write a hooking API.
- Call a function!

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose you mention, [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (wikipedia) seems a more organized solution than `comefrom`.  See the bottom of [Motiviation and Basic Concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming#Motivation_and_basic_concepts) (ibid) for an example of how logging can be added to a method in a separate textual unit.

In a sufficiently dynamic language, it is possible to handle this sort of thing using "wrap-around" modifiers to a method:

```
  def do_something
    ...
  end
  log :do_something, "Something got done"
```

In this contrived example, the `log` macro causes the `do_something` method to be replaced by a new method which first calls the original `do_something` method, and then writes something to the log.